# Simple HTML Dom getting tags values

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I have html code like this:

```
<td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="4ci66xv464x0xbdci3" data-odd="2.18"></td>
<td class="table-main__odds colored" data-oid="4ci66xv498x0x0">
    <span>
        <span>
            <span data-odd="3.68"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</td>
<td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="4ci66xv464x0xbdci4" data-odd="3.09"></td>
<td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="4ci60xv464x0xbdchn" data-odd="10.35"></td>
<td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="4ci60xv498x0x0" data-odd="6.12"></td>
<td class="table-main__odds colored" data-oid="4ci60xv464x0xbdcho">
    <span>
        <span>
            <span data-odd="1.26"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
</td>
```

I need to get data-odd values, but you can see some values are into td tag, some values are into span tag, but all are data-odd

I'm trying this approach:

```
<?php

include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

$url = "xyz";
 
function curl_request($url, $timeout = 30) {
    // Initialize curl with given url
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    // Set user-agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);

    // Write the response to a variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    // Max seconds to execute
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

    // Stop on error
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    return curl_exec($ch);
}

function get_html($url) {
    return str_get_html(curl_request($url));
}

$html = get_html($url);

$b = 0; 

$search = $html->find('td[class=table-main__odds], td[class=table-main__odds colored] span');

foreach($search as $allOdds){
    $quote = array($allOdds->href, $allOdds->innertext);
    if (isset($allOdds->attr['data-odd'])) {
        $quote['data-odd'] = $allOdds->attr['data-odd'];
    }
 
    $quotes[] = $quote;
}


    foreach($quotes as $mark) { 
    echo $mark[0]. " ";  
} 
?>
```

but I got the follow error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in... on line 33 (foreach line)

Any suggestion?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I put $html = get_html($url);

**EDIT2:** I added var_dump($quotes); after foreach cicle

**EDIT3:** My output is like this:
[see new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpbwd.jpg)

Comment: The variable `$html` does not exist at this point. You neglected to call the `get_html` function, and assign the return value to that variable.

Comment: How can I change my code? could you help me with an example? Thanks

Comment: `$html = get_html($url);` …?

Comment: ok, I edited my code, but now I got array;array;array ...sorry I am new of php, what I should do now? thanks

Comment: Start by doing a `var_dump($quotes);` after the loop, to see if this gathered the data you expected up to that point. If you then have trouble to create any sort of meaningful output in a specific, desired format from that - then you should really start by reading up on how to handle arrays in some beginner tutorial. (This is not really a place to get basics taught.)

Comment: I got values using var dump but my array is still empty. I added 2 edits and an image of my output right now (at the end there is still array;array;array)

Comment: No idea what you are trying to say here. That array is clearly not empty. _“(at the end there is still array;array;array)”_ - your array is a multi-dimensional array, so your `$oddX` variables themselves are still one-dimensional arrays - and you can not concatenate an array into a string directly, that will only get you the _word_ “Array”.

Comment: ok, I edited my post, I modify my code and you can see new pic of my output. I got the value I wanted but I don't know how I can distribuite by group of three values by row

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to get the attribute values of the `data-odd` attribute in your html, try something simple like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$odds = $xp->query('//*[@data-odd]/@data-odd');
foreach ($odds as $odd) {  
    echo($odd->value) . "\r\n";    
}
```

Output:

```
2.18

3.68

3.09

10.35

6.12

1.26
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you make the example with url, please? and I'd like to have 3 values for each row. Thanks again